# Gnome shell and unity dont show up at the login screen

Tags: unity, gnome, login

I am running kubuntu 13.04 and installed xfce desktop environment in it. From the ubuntu software center I tried to install gnome shell and unity. But when I logout I cant login to those. They both dont show up in the login screen. So I tried to install gnome using apt-get and it says that the latest version is installed. So how do I login to gnome and unity?

Comment: What commands did you use to install?  Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press CTRL+ALT+F1 then login there with your username and password. After successful login type as

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

and then check again.

Even thats not worked then go for a system restart and check again. I am sure you will have it.

Comment: I have done that and it didnt help. Tried restarting but that too failed. I have tried installing gnome using sudo apt-get install gnome-shell.

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`